# PHP Script Times Out taking too long

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Im reading a csv file that contains 1000 rows. I execute a query for each row, here is the query:

```
$foobar = 
    SELECT foo1.ID
    FROM foo1
    INNER JOIN foo2 ON foo2.ID = foo1.ID
    LEFT JOIN foo3 bar1 ON bar1.ID = foo1.ID
    LEFT JOIN foo3 bar2 ON bar2.ID = foo1.ID
    WHERE foo1.Text LIKE :txt
    AND foo2.col1 = 31 AND bar1.col1 = 138 AND bar2.col1 = 271
    AND (bar1.col2 = "" OR bar1.col2 IS NULL) 
    AND (bar2.col2 = "" OR bar2.col2 IS NULL)
```

ran **explain** on this and returned only 100 rows being searched for and constant **ref** meaning it should be fast it uses **indexes**.

Now in my loop i have the following:

```
while ($line = fgetcsv($handle)){
    $foobar->execute(); 
    $data = $foobar->fetchAll(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($data); echo '<br /><br />';
}
```

why does it take long? There are only 1000 rows in CSV file and running explain on the query seems to be fast enough.

It times out after like 5-10 minutes but it should not be taking that long i dont know whats the problem.

There is one thing to note **foo3** table contains **7** million records.

Comment: Hmmm... It's running slow because you're issuing 1,000 queries against the database?

Comment: Good thought, but 10 minutes for 1000 queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you made sure that the script can actually detect line endings? If not, then try

```
ini_set('auto_detect_line_endings',TRUE);
```

And you don't seem to be specifying the length of the data, try something like:

```
$line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)
```

And after a smort look on the PHP manual, the most used approach is to check

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($handle, 1000)) !== FALSE)
```

I also noticed that you added a \ into your fetchAll statement, try this instead:

```
fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
```

You can also do something like this to work with the data:

```
if($result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    foreach($result as $res)
    {
        foreach($res as $key=>$val)
        {
            $temp[$key] = utf8_encode($val);
        }
        array_push($array, $temp);
    }
    var_dump($array);
    echo '<br /><br />';
}
```

Your main problem might be, on the other hand, the query itself. Maybe the approach I gave you can result in a faster way.

Comment: thank you so much while ($line = fgetcsv($handle) !== FALSE) did the trick. Didnt know that !== false would make it execute instantly.

Answer (score 0):

Try start the process in console. See after exec(). The process can put datas in shared storage (mysql/file/etc...) about the process state.

Answer (score 0):

Just because a query "USES" indexes, does not mean that "it should be fast". The speed depends on whether the "correct" indexes are available to be used and if the query is constructed to be efficient.

For example, your query uses:

```
WHERE foo1.Text LIKE :txt
```

If there are many rows in foo1 and/or foo1.Text is a large (i.e. a TEXT type field) and :txt maybe begins with a %, then that means that the primary table will be unable to use an index.

Also, all the required join indexes may not be in place. For instance, it is obvious from your query that the field foo3.ID is not a primary key..

To better answer the question "why does it take long?", I would need more information about the structures of the tables foo1/2/3.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that just one of the rows is being problematic? I would start by running this from the CLI; change the output to just log the index of the row and the time it took to execute. This should help clarify the problem.